# MinMaxScaler not scaling correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I am using sklearn MinMaxScaler code I got off of Lynda.com to scale my data sets for a prediction code. The feature ranger should be (0,1) but I noticed on my trial data that some columns are larger than 1. I believe this is causing my prediction code to not come out right. Can anybody help? Belo is the code I am using...

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preproMinmaxcessing import MinMaxScaler

# Load training data set from CSV file
training_data_df = pd.read_csv("10596_data_training.csv")

# Load testing data set from CSV file
test_data_df = pd.read_csv("10596_data_test.csv")

# Load the trial data set from CSV file
trial_data_df = pd.read_csv("day05.csv")

# Data needs to be scaled to a small range like 0 to 1 for the neural
# network to work well.
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

# Scale both the training inputs and outputs
scaled_training = scaler.fit_transform(training_data_df)
scaled_testing = scaler.transform(test_data_df)
scaled_trial = scaler.transform(trial_data_df)

# Print out the adjustment that the scaler applied to the total_earnings column of data
print("Note: total_hours values were scaled by multiplying by {:.10f} and     adding {:.6f}".format(scaler.scale_[40], scaler.min_[40]))

# Create new pandas DataFrame objects from the scaled data
scaled_training_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_training,      columns=training_data_df.columns.values)
scaled_testing_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_testing,     columns=test_data_df.columns.values)
scaled_trial_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_trial, columns=trial_data_df.columns.values)

# Save scaled data dataframes to new CSV files
scaled_training_df.to_csv("10596_data_training_scaled.csv", index=False)
scaled_testing_df.to_csv("10596_data_test_scaled.csv", index=False)
scaled_trial_df.to_csv("day05_scaled.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 5):

You're "training" your MinMaxScaler on a subset of your data, and then transforming a different subset.  The MinMaxScaler is simply subtracting the minimum of the training set and then dividing by the max.  If the trial set has values greater than the max of the training set or less than the min of the training set, you'll have values outside of the [0,1] range.  This is expected and acceptable.

Comment: To re-scale the data from the 0 to 1 range, is the 0 value acceptable? For example: prediction = prediction + 0.00000, prediction = prediction / 0.0045372051

Comment: Sure - the only reason you're scaling in the first place is because many ML algorithms don't handle wildly different scales well.  There isn't anything special, generally, about a zero-valued datapoint.